# Access to nth bit without a conditional statement

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, truthtable

So I have a bit sequence:

1010

1 is the MSB.

My function needs to return an integer of 0 if an odd bit is 0 or a 1 if its a 1.

I cannot use any for loops or anything of that nature to see if I need to return a 0 or 1. Does anyone have any suggestions how to go about this.

I was thinking about using a not operation but I can figure out how to exactly use it.

So far I am using a sequence of 1010...10 and then anding it. Doing that to the above would get me 1010. Now I need to find out if I return a 1 or a 0.

Comment: Is this homework? You will want to use the bitwise-and (`&`) operator. You could even use the bitwise-or (`|`), but `&` is more convenient in this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say we're talking about 32bit integers. I assume you want to know if ANY ODD bit is SET (1).

To do this we create an integer that looks like this:

```
10101010101010101010101010101010
```

Now, if we AND (`&`) by this, all the even bits get filtered out. Now if the number is not zero one or more odd bits were set. In C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int hasodd(uint32_t x) {
    // 0xAAAAAAAA = 10101010101010101010101010101010
    // double negation to turn x>0 into 1 and leave 0 alone
    return !!(x & 0xAAAAAAAA); 
}
```

If you meant that you should return whether the Nth bit is set, this works. It right-shifts a `1` to the correct position to filter out all the irrelevant bits:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int nthbitset(uint32_t x, int n) {
    return x & (1 << n);
}
```

Comment: Well the thing is I can only use 8 bits make, so only AA of that. I was thinking about shifting the bits over 24 spots, get those 8 and then and it. Then in another variable shift over 16 bits and and it with a slightly different number to replace the 8 bits that are infront of it. After that though I dont know how to combine them if that would work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @David: Could you rephrase please? I didn't get anything.

Comment: So I can only play with chunks like this: 10011100 00110101 11010000 00010101. I need to evaulate each chunk to see if it had an even that was tagged in my and. So I shift each chunk either 24,16 or 8 over and then and and now I will have my tagged values. How can I combine them or figure out if there was a 1 in any of my chunks?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fuzzy about the intent of your question—it seem like homework.  Depending on what your actual needs are (like is says in the question title or in the text), one of these will work in most any `C` implementation:

```
int hasoddbitset (int v)
{
     return (v & 0xaaaaaaaa) != 0;  // for 32 bit ints
}

int isbitset (int val, int bitnum)
{
     return (val & (1 << bitnum)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that your code is exactly the same as mine while mine (save the conditionals) and was posted 12 minutes earlier. Please consider removing the answer or add new information.

Comment: Well congratulations... You still managed to get two upvotes for this. BTW, your `isbitset` function is broken, tip: look at `bitnum`.

Comment: @nightcracker:  my code is less verbose and uses more direct operations to achieve its results, so it is not "exactly the same", otherwise I would not have posted it.  While `!!` is valid, it is obscure and most likely needless—ever.  (Thanks for pointing out the mistake:  it is removed.)